# SQL Server Job execution after the job stopped

Tags: sql-server, job-scheduling, eventhandler

I started one a job from the ‘Job Activity Monitor’, I stopped the job after few minutes once I realized that this is not the job I should be running. The next day, the stopped job triggered by the scheduler did not run the job from the beginning it seems, as usually what it does daily.

The log shows something  ‘OnPostExecute ’ & ‘OnPostValidate’ messages, where it use to show ‘Succeeded’ text on a regular execution. There was no data load happen, the job completed in just couple of minutes where it usually takes around 9 min.

When I re executed the job, all was good, data was loaded, Result tab showed ‘Succeeded’ text.

I would like to understand what actually happened? What can I do to make the scheduler run the job from the beginning not from where it was stopped?

How can I stop this happening on the next time, when a job is stopped and the scheduler executes on the next day on its usual time the job should be started from the beginning.

Comment: The Job Scheduler will start the job from the step you told it to, though it often is this may not be the start, and it won't be from where it got to last time.

Comment: Look at the job log and you will see which steps were executed and when and who started the job

Comment: Will there be a difference when a job triggered by the scheduler  & the job ran manually, stopped in the middle and thereafter triggered by the scheduler? is there anyway I can control whenever is some job ran accidentally should get start usually rather than starting differently then usual?

Comment: You can see the user started the job as well as the steps being ran and their output, so i'm guessing the answer is yes